# SpringMVC, Jquery, ajax post rises error function

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I don't know why the call to the Controller rises the error Ajax Jquery function. The controller function is executed successfully and return "OK". And the "e" parameter of the error function is undefined.

I have this code

**Controller code - SpringMVC**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateItem/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateItem(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, 
    @RequestParam("id") String id, ...) {
        //Operations
        return "OK";
}
```

**Jquery code**

```
  function updateItem() {
     $.ajax({
        url : "/.../updateItem/",
            type : 'POST',
            async : false,
            data : {
                id : id.value,
                ...
            },
            success: function(response) { alert("second success"); },
            error: function(e) { alert("error " + e);},
            complete: function() { alert("complete"); },
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up chrome, press f12 to open up the dev tools, look at console / network

what is the error from post you are getting in both tabs?

Your code looks alright btw.

Comment: Thanks friend, I found the problem, the controller didn't know what to do with "OK", so I have changed the String to a valid "address".